# Объединение свойств CSS

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, возможно ли сократить данный код:

```
div[class*='price'], span[class*='price'] {
    color: #018259;
}
```

В области указания элемента, чтобы два раза не перечислять, а сделать что-то на подобии: `div/span[class*='price']`

Comment: [class*='price']

Answer (score 4):

Можно задать параметр для конкретного класса

```
.price {
    color: #018259;
}
```